# KeystoneJS get ObjectID from another value

Tags: node.js, keystonejs

I want to get the ObjectID from a category by using slug path (key)

this is the model (its the default from keystone generator)

```
var keystone = require('keystone');

/**
 * PostCategory Model
 * ==================
 */

var PostCategory = new keystone.List('PostCategory', {
    autokey: { from: 'name', path: 'key', unique: true },
});

PostCategory.add({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
});

PostCategory.relationship({ ref: 'Post', path: 'categories' });

PostCategory.register();
```

Heres what i get from mongoshell

db.getCollection('postcategories').find({"key":"test"})

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5853a502455e60d5282d9325"),
    "key" : "test",
    "name" : "test",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

This is just to find if the key works
but when i use this on routes

```
var gc = "test";
var c = keystone.list('PostCategory').model.find().where('key').equals(gc);
 c.key = gc;
console.log(gc ,c.id);
```

The log says test undefined.
i tried to use postcategories as well but it says keystone doesnt recognize it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's pick up our discussion from your [keystone issue](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/3814) here.

The reason should be that `find()` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), so the operation is ran asynchronously. Therefore, at the moment you log the value, it's still `undefined`.

There are examples of the promises on the keystone demo site, for example [here](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone-demo/blob/master/routes/views/blog.js#L22).

I think what you want is something like:

```
var gc = "test";
var c = keystone.list('PostCategory').model.find().where('key').equals(gc).exec(function (err, results) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(results);
    }
});
```

or

```
keystone
   .list('PostCategory')
   .model
   .find()
   .where('key')
   .equals(gc)
   .then(function(category) {
      console.log(category.id);
});
```

Also, I'm not sure here but if `find({"key":"test"})` works in mongoshell, it might also work in mongoose, so have you tried `keystone.list('PostCategory').model.find({"key":"test"}).exec(...)`?

Comment: the mongo shell works fine. i did it only to find if the key worked i don't really need it for anything else the first example works fine but i am still not sure how to get the id the second example doesn't seem to work maybe i am missing something

Comment: You'll be able to extract the ID as e.g. `results[0]._id` for the first result.

Answer (score 0):

```
var gc = test; ?????
```

obviously test is not defined. from Javascript perspective.
JS expects test to be a variable.  and it dont know what is DB at that moment.

Comment: what do you mean? that is the key value

Comment: if i use ObjectID instead of key it works so now i want to get ObjectID by using the key

Comment: `test` is not defined in your JavaScript, hence the error. You just need it in quotes, surely? `"test"`

Comment: ooh i forgot to add it inside quotes here really sorry about that